# What is the $\partial \mathbb{R}_+^n$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Why is $\partial \mathbb{R}_+^n \cong \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ true?

Comment: You have to specify the meaning the the symbol $\partial$: There are two (in general inequivalent) definitions common in topology. You should also explain what did you try to solve this problem.

Comment: Explain what is meant by ${\mathbb R}_+^n$.

Comment: Here $\mathbb{R}^n_{+}:=\{(x_1, \dots, x_n): x_n>0, x_i\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Just the definition in the PDE. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can define the following homeomorphism:

$\psi(x_1,\dots , x_{n-1}, 0):=(x_1,\dots ,x_{n-1})$